# Generate all possible splits of a list in Python

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have a `list` in python:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

I want to generate all the possible splits of this `list`:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[1] [2,3,4]
[2] [1,3,4]
[3] [1,2,4]
[4] [1,2,3]
[1,2] [3,4]
[1,3] [2,4]
[1,4] [2,3]
```

What is the best way to do this?  I can generate the first side with `itertools.combinations()`, but what is the easiest way to calculate the remainder, given the `list` and a `subset`?

Comment: Maybe combine `itertools.combinations` with some moving window function?

Comment: Does the ordering matter or just the contents (like your example)?

Comment: "*What is the best way to do this?*" - It's hard to say which way is the best. How many ways have you tried?

Comment: Is `[1] [2] [3] [4]` also a valid split?

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
subsets = [v for a in range(len(x)) for v in combinations(x, a)]
for i in range(len(subsets)/2 + 1):
    print list(chain(subsets[i])), ' ', [e for e in x if e not in subsets[i]]
```

output:

```
[]   [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1]   [2, 3, 4]
[2]   [1, 3, 4]
[3]   [1, 2, 4]
[4]   [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2]   [3, 4]
[1, 3]   [2, 4]
[1, 4]   [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list-comprehension` to get the remainder:

```
[x for x in a if x not in b]
```

assuming `a` is the original `list` and `b` is the `subset` you got.

**EDIT:**

If you want to avoid duplicates you can create a list to check before printing and in the same time check for empty remainder (full list):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [list(c) for i in xrange(len(a)) for c in itertools.combinations(a, i+1)]
check = []
for elem in b:
    remainder = [x for x in a if x not in elem]
    if remainder not in check and remainder:
        print '{} {}'.format(elem, remainder)
        check.append(elem)
```

output:

```
[1] [2, 3, 4]
[2] [1, 3, 4]
[3] [1, 2, 4]
[4] [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2] [3, 4]
[1, 3] [2, 4]
[1, 4] [2, 3]
```

Comment: Can you give an example input and output?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to turn them both into sets and do a simple set difference.

```
full = [1, 2, 3, 4]
full_set = set(full)
for partition in itertools.combinations(...):
    remainder = list(full_set - set(partition))
    print partition, remainder
```

Comment: i think it will produce duplicate sets

Comment: @Fabricator `combinations` produces lists that turn into unique sets.  Perhaps you're thinking of permutations?  I did leave that sketchy, since OP indicates that he's familiar with generating the unique lists.

Comment: I'm saying [[1,2],[3,4]] and [[3,4],[1,2]] are duplicates

Comment: Ah ... but I gather that OP is not stuck at that point -- and SO is not a place to come for full coding solutions.  I'm just getting him over the hump of determining the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> for i in range(len(x)):
...     for c in [c for c in itertools.combinations(x, i+1)]:
...             print(list(c), [i for i in x if not i in c])
...
[1] [2, 3, 4]
[2] [1, 3, 4]
[3] [1, 2, 4]
[4] [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2] [3, 4]
[1, 3] [2, 4]
[1, 4] [2, 3]
[2, 3] [1, 4]
[2, 4] [1, 3]
[3, 4] [1, 2]
[1, 2, 3] [4]
[1, 2, 4] [3]
[1, 3, 4] [2]
[2, 3, 4] [1]
[1, 2, 3, 4] []
```